# Duplicate Results with LISTAGG Function

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I do see there are solutions for a similar question but I was unable to get them to work in my scenario.
I am returning duplicate codes while using the LISTAGG function. 
Returning now:

[image]

```
SELECT 
,CD.CLAIM
,CD.CLAIMLN
,CD.PROV_INVOICE_UNTS
,CD.APPR_UNTS
,CD.PROV_INVOICE_AMT
,CD.PROV_CNTRCT_AMT
,CD.PLAN_CNTRCT_AMT as PLAN_AMT
,LISTAGG(DX.DIAG_CD,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DX.LVL_CD)  AS DX_CODES

FROM CLAIM_DETAIL CD
INNER JOIN PATIENT_INTAKE_PLAN PIP
ON CD.PAT_NBR = PIP.PAT_NBR AND CD.ITK_ID = PIP.ITK_ID
INNER JOIN HEALTH_PLAN HP
ON HP.PLAN_ID = PIP.PLAN_ID
INNER JOIN PROVIDER_CCXPORTAL PR
ON PR.PROV_ID = CD.PROV_ID
INNER JOIN PROVIDER_PARENT PRP
ON PR.PROV_PRNT_ID = PRP.PROV_PRNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATIENT_CCXPORTAL PTP
ON PTP.PAT_NBR = CD.PAT_NBR 
INNER JOIN CLAIM C
ON C.CLM_ID = CD.CLM_ID
LEFT JOIN CLAIM_DIAGNOSIS DX
ON CD.CLM_ID = DX.CLM_ID

WHERE 
C.RCPT_DT >= '01-JUL-2014'
```

I need it to return:
[image]

Comment: Your query is incomplete.  You have `list_agg()`, but no `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi Gordon, I do have the group by function I just didn't copy far enough down. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex to get rid of the duplicates

```
....as PLAN_AMT,
RTRIM(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           (listagg(DX.DIAG_CD,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DX.LVL_CD) ), 
           '([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)', 
           '\1\3'),
         ',') AS DX_CODES
FROM......
```

Comment: I tried that before as I saw that as a solution on another post but I got an error after running saying the string was too long

Comment: @tia97 Can you edit your question with the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

If there are very many DX_CODES per claim, your may string exceed the max length for a SQL varchar2.

Can you try this instead?

```
SELECT 
,CD.CLAIM
,CD.CLAIMLN
,CD.PROV_INVOICE_UNTS
,CD.APPR_UNTS
,CD.PROV_INVOICE_AMT
,CD.PROV_CNTRCT_AMT
,CD.PLAN_CNTRCT_AMT as PLAN_AMT
, (SELECT listagg(dx.diag_cd,',') within group ( order by dx.lvl_cd, dx.diag_cd ) FROM ( SELECT distinct clm_id, lvl_cd, diag_cd FROM claim_diagnosis ) dx WHERE dx.clm_id = cd.clm_id ) dx_codes
--,LISTAGG(DX.DIAG_CD,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DX.LVL_CD)  AS DX_CODES
FROM CLAIM_DETAIL CD
INNER JOIN PATIENT_INTAKE_PLAN PIP
ON CD.PAT_NBR = PIP.PAT_NBR AND CD.ITK_ID = PIP.ITK_ID
INNER JOIN HEALTH_PLAN HP
ON HP.PLAN_ID = PIP.PLAN_ID
INNER JOIN PROVIDER_CCXPORTAL PR
ON PR.PROV_ID = CD.PROV_ID
INNER JOIN PROVIDER_PARENT PRP
ON PR.PROV_PRNT_ID = PRP.PROV_PRNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATIENT_CCXPORTAL PTP
ON PTP.PAT_NBR = CD.PAT_NBR 
INNER JOIN CLAIM C
ON C.CLM_ID = CD.CLM_ID
--LEFT JOIN CLAIM_DIAGNOSIS DX
--ON CD.CLM_ID = DX.CLM_ID
WHERE 
C.RCPT_DT >= '01-JUL-2014'
```

Make sure there is an index on CLAIM_DIAGNOSIS.CLM_ID.